# Are there md5 collisions for integers in range(1,1000000000)

Tags: python, hash, md5, uuid, guid

I want to generate a uuid in python using the md5 hash of a preexisting unique identifier ranged between 1 and 999999999

It seems obvious that on numbers so small there couldn't be any worry... but it made me think, do we know the smallest two integers that have the same md5 hash ?

Comment: You can check MD5 collisions here:http://www.mscs.dal.ca/~selinger/md5collision/

Comment: I just take your text "the smallest two integers that have the same md5 hash" to search on google and find this answer: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/15877. It gives 2^64

Comment: Merci Reblochon Masqué ! Pretty cool link, I will add it to my bookmarks, but it has no answer on integers :/

Comment: Thanks @Sraw, If I understood your link well, we know that those minima are somewhere between 2^36 and 2^64 at best, but we have no way to find those other than bruteforce... Am I right ?

Comment: @VincentChalmel: Indeed.

Comment: There is not. And I'm about 1:3.4×10²⁹ sure.

Comment: There isn't. If they were a collision for such small numbers, you'd know about it.

Comment: Very likely @ErikDuminil, but not proof positive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tested, and the answer is no.

counting with `set()` will trigger `MemoryError` on my 64GB memory box, so I write hexlify hash to disk:

```
import hashlib
from multiprocessing import Pool
import os

def f(args):
    s, e = args
    l = []
    for i in xrange(s, e):
        h = hashlib.md5(str(i)).hexdigest()
        l.append(h)
    l.sort()
    fn = '/data/tmp/%s_%s' % (s, e)
    with open(fn, 'w') as f:
        for h in l:
            f.write('%s\n' % (h,))

def main():
    def gen():
        end = 1000000000
        step = 5000000
        s = 0
        while s < end:
            yield s, s+step
            s += step

    pool = Pool(processes=16)
    res = pool.imap_unordered(f, gen())
    list(res)
```

then counting with `sort(1)`:

```
sort -mu /data/tmp/* | wc -l
```

yields:

```
1000000000
```

note that I encoded integer into ASCII string.

Answer (score 1):

You could test it:

> **provided you have ample memory, and/or an OS that manages excess
>   memory usage with disk access, but then it will be rather slow -
>   thanks to @EricDuminil & @vsenko in the comments**

```
import hashlib

h = hashlib.new('md5', buffer=64)
md5hashes = set()

N = 1000000000

for _ in range(N):
    if _ % 10000000 == 0:
        print(".", flush = True)
    h.update(str(_).encode())
    hsh = h.hexdigest()
    if hsh in md5hashes:
        print(_, hsh)
    md5hashes.add(hsh)


print(f"has collisions: {len(md5hashes) != N})
```

Comment: You might run into a `MemoryError`.

Comment: Minor nitpick: The question is "Are there collisions?". So your last boolean should  probably be `len(md5hashes) != N`

Comment: It will require a huge amount of RAM.

Comment: Yes, that's going to require memory management, it is not very practical, or it is going to be very slow with plenty of disk access. And yes, `!=` is better.

Answer (score 1):

You could test it using MongoDb as data store:

```
import hashlib
import sys
import pymongo

def int_to_bytes(x):
    return x.to_bytes((x.bit_length() + 7) // 8, byteorder=sys.byteorder)

CLIENT = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
DB = CLIENT['md5test']
COLLECTION = DB['vals']

COLLECTION.create_index('value', unique=True)

for x in range(1000000000):
    if x % 1000000 == 0:
        print(x)
    m = hashlib.md5()
    m.update(int_to_bytes(x))
    value = m.digest()
    COLLECTION.insert_one({
        'value': value
    })

print('done!')
```

It will throw in case of a duplicate. But it will take time to process your range.

Also it matters how you encode integers, see `int_to_bytes()`.